# Raku slow Mixes sorting

Tags: performance, sorting, raku

### Update

On the same computer, using the Rakudo compiler "rakudo-moar-2021.06-01-macos-x86_64-clang.tar" I get 3-10 times speed-ups compared to the timings of my calculations in the original post.

```
.elems: 100000
.head(3): (id.20444 => 81.95246687507492 id.81745 => 34.859323339828464 id.79973 => 97.33816856420829)
time of .sort({-$_.value}) : 0.764283216
time of .sort(-*.value)    : 0.618963783
time of .sort.reverse      : 0.584477656
time of .values.sort       : 1.68912663
```

Note, that those timings are close to the R timings. So, on those kinds of computations Raku has the performance I expect.

---

### Original post

I recently watched a FOSDEM presentation by Elizabeth Mattijsen titled
["Raku - Sets without Borders"](https://fosdem.org/2021/schedule/event/raku_sets_without_borders/)
and decided to adopt Raku `Mix` objects in some of my computational workflows.

I noticed that sorting (the pairs of) a `Mix` object is very slow -- I would say 100 to 1000 times slower than what I expect. See the Raku code and output below. (I also provided related R code and output on the same computer.)

Is that slowness expected? Is there a work around for faster computations?

(To be more specific, I am interested in fast reverse-sort and fast retrieval of the top-K largest elements in a `Mix`.)

(The timings are on a few years old Mac Book Pro, Mac OS 10.15.7, using latest Rakudo Compiler "rakudo-moar-2021.02.1-01-macos-x86_64-clang.tar.gz" .)

### Raku

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

my @words = Array(1 .. 100_000).map({ 'id.' ~ $_.Str });
my $m0 = Mix(@words.map({ $_ => 100.rand() }));
say '.elems: ', $m0.elems;
say '.head(3): ', $m0.head(3);

my $start = now;
my $m1 = $m0.sort({-$_.value});
say 'time of .sort({-$_.value}): ', now - $start;

$start = now;
my $m2 = $m0.sort(-*.value);
say 'time of .sort(-*.value)   : ', now - $start;

$start = now;
my $m3 = $m0.sort.reverse;
say 'time of .sort.reverse     : ', now - $start;

$start = now;
my $m4 = $m0.values.sort;
say 'time of .values.sort      : ', now - $start;

# .elems: 100000
# .head(3): (id.96239 => 87.89629474533156 id.89110 => 11.661698290245525 id.24795 => # 64.80528155838671)
# time of .sort({-$_.value}): 3.64936396
# time of .sort(-*.value)   : 4.0388654
# time of .sort.reverse     : 4.5783556
# time of .values.sort      : 4.3461059
```

### R

Here is a similar data and sorting code in R:

```r
words <- paste0( 'id.', 1:100000)
m <- setNames( runif(n = length(words), min = 0, max = 100), words)
cat( "length(m)                          : ", length(m), "\n")
cat( "m[1:3]:\n"); print(m[1:3]); cat("\n")
cat( "system.time( sort(m) )             : ", system.time( sort(m) ), "\n")
cat( "system.time( m[order(-m)] )        : ", system.time( m[order(-m)] ), "\n")
cat( "system.time( rev(sort(names(m))) ) : ", system.time( rev(sort(names(m))) ), "\n")

# length(m)                          :  100000 
# m[1:3]:
#     id.1     id.2     id.3 
# 89.99714 54.31701 11.57415 
#
# system.time( sort(m) )             :  0.011 0     0.011 0 0 
# system.time( m[order(-m)] )        :  0.011 0     0.011 0 0 
# system.time( rev(sort(names(m))) ) :  0.298 0.001 0.3   0 0
```

Here are answers to questions by @raith:

- "Is the m in the R code mutable?"
  No, R objects are mostly immutable.
- "Does the sort(m) build a new data structure, or just a new index into the existing m structure?"
  A new data structure is created. R is a descendent of LISP, so it mostly follows, in spirit, the functional programming paradigm.
- "Same question for m[order(-m)]?"
  `order(-m)` gives an integer vector (of indexes.) That vector of indexes is used to retrieve elements of `m` into a new object.
- "And rev(sort(names(m)))?"
  `names(m)` takes the "keys" of `m`'s elements. Those keys are sorted and placed into a character vector, and then that character vector is reversed. (I.e. a new object is created.)
- "Presumably building just an index could be dramatically faster. Perhaps Raku could have a sort variant for Tuples that produces a Seq that relies
  on that approach?"
  *I assume it is not my place to comment on this,* but I would like to mention that:

  - Julia -- which is also a LISP descendant -- does something like that for its data structures. And Julia's creators and developers claim to be, in general, (much) faster than R and Mathematica. (Which are other LISP descendants for mathematical computations.)
  - I prefer and expect Raku code in the functional paradigm style to be fast.

#### Updated R benchmark

A few people requested more detailed R benchmarking:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(32)
words <- paste0( 'id.', 1:100000)
m <- setNames( runif(n = length(words), min = 0, max = 100), words)
cat( "length(m): ", length(m), "\n")
cat( "m[1:3]:\n"); print(m[1:3]); cat("\n")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sort(m, decreasing = T),
  sort(-m),
  m[order(-m)],
  rev(sort(m)),
  rev(sort(names(m))),
  unit = "s", times = 100
)

# length(m) :  100000
#
# m[1:3]:
#     id.1     id.2     id.3
# 50.58405 59.48084 80.87471
#
# Unit: seconds
#                     expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval cld
#  sort(m, decreasing = T) 0.006246853 0.007789205 0.009215613 0.008263348 0.009002414 0.02450786   100 a
#                 sort(-m) 0.006857755 0.008376058 0.010292145 0.008939605 0.010069702 0.02469324   100 a
#             m[order(-m)] 0.006658089 0.008257555 0.009726704 0.008718414 0.009811200 0.02294023   100 a
#             rev(sort(m)) 0.008975013 0.010939122 0.014965756 0.011692480 0.012571979 0.22022085   100  b
#      rev(sort(names(m))) 0.256036106 0.268526455 0.278385866 0.277794917 0.288586351 0.31160492   100   c
#
```

Comment: I'll note that this doesn't seem to be particularly tied to `Mix`es.  Directly sorting similar `Array` (e.g., `my @a = (1 .. 100_000).map({100.rand}); @a.sort(-*)`) has similar performance characteristics.  I'll be interested to see the answers to this question.

Comment: @codesections Good point. I experiment with `Hash` objects and got similar outcomes, but did not try it out with `Array` objects. (Although, that is sort of covered with the `m4` line, `$m0.values.sort;`, in my post.)

Comment: I'm not sure we'll be able to match R in performance any time soon, but looking at a profile, it looks like the `Mu.Bool` proto and its dispatch to `Int.Bool` is not getting inlined (when it clearly should), and is thus responsible for about 50% of the CPU used in the example code.  Investigating...

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen What command line and viewer did you use for the profile? Just `raku --profile program.raku` and load the result in a web browser or something more elaborate?

Comment: @raiph just that  :-)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thank you for your comment. And thank you for your "Raku - Sets without Borders" presentation! I found it inspiring...

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/70a8e3661f improves the situation: timings before on my machine:

time of .sort({-$_.value}): 2.8491583
time of .sort(-*.value)   : 2.78743497
time of .sort.reverse     : 3.508573
time of .values.sort      : 3.05211257

and after:

time of .sort({-$_.value}): 1.6635785
time of .sort(-*.value)   : 1.568134
time of .sort.reverse     : 2.061565934
time of .values.sort      : 1.75952683

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Per [R's `system.time`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/system.time), "should a garbage collection be performed immediately before the timing? Default is TRUE.".

Comment: Is the `m` in the R code mutable? Does the `sort(m)` build a new data structure, or just a new index into the existing `m` structure? Same question for `m[order(-m)]`? And `rev(sort(names(m)))`? Presumably building just an index could be dramatically faster. Perhaps Raku could have a `sort` variant for `Tuple`s that produces a `Seq` that relies on that approach?

Comment: Rakudo already optimizes sort for native arrays, and internally uses an in-place sort when it determines it can do so.  Furthermore, I've identified some more optimisable comparators that even further speedup the op's code.

Comment: @raiph Good R-code related questions -- I answered them in the post. (I have used R for a long time, so I am prone to *not* give sufficient background of its features...)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Great to see the speedup commit! "internally uses an in-place sort when it determines it can do so." Presumably one of the inputs to that determination is escape analysis, right? Is spotting that a `sort` was triggered by code of the form `array.=sort` another input? If not, could it be? Do you see what I mean about the potentially dramatic advantage of building a `Seq` or some similar approach when sorting some immutable composite data structure? One day -- not this year, but one day?

Comment: @raiph  One day, yeah  :-)   Meanwhile there's a good chance that the `@array .= sort` case will be optimizable to be in-place when RakuAST has landed.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen "One day, yeah". Is that comment about escape analysis being used when determining it's OK to sort in place for a *mutable* structure, or building a `Seq` index when sorting an *immutable* structure?

Comment: @AntonAntonov Raku is clearly a heck of a lot slower. It might be helpful for better establishing the general takeaway from your benchmarks if you ran them, almost exactly as you have them, but repeating the expression 100 times (so, same list size -- 100,000, but repeat each sort 100 times) and, for the R code, using `system.time( expr-repeated-100-times, gcFirst = FALSE)` for the R timing, so allowing R's GC to go ahead, as it is with your Raku code, making the comparison more apples-to-apples. Rakudo *may* then be proportionally even slower, but it would be useful info one way or the other.

Comment: @raiph: you don't need escape analysis to be able to make `@a .= sort`: the AST gives that information already.  I have been thinking on using a binary chop on uncached `Seq`s when sorting a `Seq`, so it would build the result while consuming the `Seq`.

Comment: At the very least this is an imprecise comparison between Raku and R (and Mathematica, and Julia, etc). Within my albeit older version of R there are at least three `sort()` methods available: `shell`, `quick`, and `radix`.  R's `sort()` function is related to  `order()` and `rank()` which in turn depend on `xtfrm()`, an `internal generic primitive`. According to `?sort()` the `radix` sort method, (derived from the `data.table` package/authors), is generally considered the fastest. See: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/08/r-tip-consider-radix-sort/

Comment: @jubilatious1 The point of my post was not a comparison between Raku and R. I put the R code and timings just to support my proclaimed speed expectations.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Please put your comments into an answer -- then I can accept it. (Of course, I do like [the answer by @codesections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66500447).)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen Thx. I had misunderstood what underpinned the determination. "you don't need escape analysis to be able to make `@a .= sort` [be in-place]" Right. The dev has asked to do an in-place sort, so go ahead and do it. "Rakudo already ... internally uses an in-place sort when it determines it can do so." is presumably the same deal of presuming devs know what they're doing, i.e. core Raku philosophy. I now realize that whether code is actually faulty due to having somehow shared a to-be-sorted data reference with another thread (i.e. it's escaped) is a separate unrelated problem.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Hi Anton, it would still be interesting to know your comparative timings if you added the parameter `, method = "radix"` to your `sort()` calls in R. Also, since you're interested in sorting in reverse order, R can do that in one call:  simply add the parameter `, decreasing = TRUE` to your `sort()` calls. Thx.

Comment: @jubilatious1 The first R code I posted is supposed to resemble the Raku
code. That is why I used in R `rev(sort(m))` -- it corresponds to
`$m.values.sort.reverse` in Raku. But since you and @raiph requested more
detailed R benchmarking, I updated my post with such code and results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a deficiency in the way comparisons were made with `.sort`, which resulted in a lot of calls to the `Mu.Bool` method, which in some cases would make up about 50% of CPU used.  Today I have changed the handling of `.sort` for non-standard comparisons in such a way that the call to `Mu.Bool` is no longer made.  This resulted in the code of the question to run about 2x as fast as before, although @codesections reported a 4x speed increase.  This should be in the 2020.03 release.

Comment: Is that % or x ?

Comment: With Rakudo compiler "rakudo-moar-2021.06-01-macos-x86_64-clang.tar" I get 3-10 times speed-ups of the timings. (Last time I mentioned much greater speed-ups, because my "new benchmark" mix was 10 times smaller.)

Answer (score 8):

[**EDIT** 2021-03-06: thanks to a series of commits over the past ~day (thanks, Liz!), this slowdown is now largely fixed on `HEAD`; these performance gains should show up in the next monthly release.  I'm leaving the answer below as an example of how to dig into this sort of issue, but the specific problems it diagnosed have largely been resolved.]

Building on @Elizabeth Mattijsen's comment: The slow performance here is **mostly** due to the Rakudo compiler not properly optimizing the generated code (as of 2021-03-05).  As the compiler continues to improve, the (idiomatic) code you wrote above should perform much better.

However, for today we can use a few workarounds to speed up this calculation.  While it's still true that Raku's performance won't be particularly competitive with R here, some profiling-driven refactoring can make this code nearly **an order of magnitude faster**.

Here's how we do it:

First, we start by profiling the code.  If you run your script with `raku --profile=<filename>`, then you'll get a profile written to `<filename>`.  By default, this will be an HTML file that allows you to view the profile in your browser.  My preference, however, is to specify an `.sql` extension, which generates an SQL profile.  I then view this profile with [MoarProf](https://github.com/timo/moarperf), the revised profiler that [Timo Paulssen](https://wakelift.de/) is building.

Looking at this profile shows exactly the issue that Liz mentioned: Calls that should be getting inlined are not.  To fix this, let's create our own sorting function, which the JIT compiler will happily optimize:

```
sub my-reverse($a, $b) {
    $a.value > $b.value ?? Order::Less !! Order::More
}
```

Using this function (with `$m0.sort(&my-reverse)`) immediately shaves a good 25% off the runtime, but it's still way too high.  Back to the profiler!

The next thing that jumps out at me is that we still have far too many calls to `Bool`.  In particular, it looks like Rakudo is currently converting `Ordering` to a `Bool`.  I *think* this is a bug and plan to look into it after posting this, but in any event, we can save Rakudo the effort:

```
sub my-reverse1($a, $b) {
    $a.value > $b.value ?? False !! True
}
```

On my machine, this cuts execution time in half again, getting us to ~28% of the original runtime of of `.sort({-$_.value})`.  This is getting decent, and would be a fine place to stop.

Let's pres on, though: checking the profiler again shows that we're still devoting a very large chunk of our time to calling `Bool` (even though we're calling in half as often).  To fix this at the moment, we'll need to drop down to [NQP](https://github.com/Raku/nqp/blob/master/docs/ops.markdown) to compare numbers without constructing a `Bool`:

```
sub nqp-reverse($a, $b) {
    use nqp;
    nqp::isge_n($a.value, $b.value) ?? False !! True
}
```

This cuts our execution time in half again, and gets us to about the performance that I'd want out of Raku.

Here are the timing results I get, both for the functions I added and the ones in your question, reported in the same format you used:

```
.elems: 100000
.head(3): (id.195 => 80.81458886131459 id.31126 => 84.25690944480021 id.60237 => 45.63311676798485)
time of .sort(&nqp-reverse): 0.3226533
time of .sort(&my-reverse1): 0.76803384
time of .sort(&my-reverse) : 1.4643238
time of .sort({-$_.value}) : 2.6780952
time of .sort(-*.value)    : 1.8549689
time of .sort.reverse      : 2.5862973
time of .values.sort       : 2.078715
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very instructive.

Answer (score 1):

On a slight aside, there are some Raku idioms that can streamline a bit...

```
my @words = Array(1 .. 100_000).map({ 'id.' ~ $_.Str });
my $m0 = Mix(@words.map({ $_ => 100.rand() }));
```

to

```
my $m0 = .map(* => 100.rand).Mix given 'id.' X~ 1..100_000;
```

this employs the ['given'](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/given%20statement) formulation and the [X metaoperator](https://docs.raku.org/routine/X) with '~' string concatenation.

Comment: I upvoted, but this is not an answer, it is a comment.